# Getting a dictionary for each feature of a layer with their attribute values using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, attribute-table, dictionary

I need to obtain, for each feature of a layer, a dictionary with the attribute names and its values using PyQGIS.

I can get all the attributes of the layer using

```py
indiv = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Individuos')[0]

for feature in features:
    value = feature[field.name()]
    attrs = feature.attributes()
    print(attrs)
```

But what I need is to create a dictionary with field names as key and their value for each feature.

Comment: please show us how far you have got - this will help get you started https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/working_with_attributes.html

Comment: Ok, I modified the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Please do not delete and repost closed questions

Comment: Sorry @IanTurton, I am quite new with this and I did not know how to do with a closed question.

Comment: you need to improve the question and then wait for it to be reopened by the community or a moderator